# Could the developer survey have a save and continue feature?

Tags: feature-request, survey

The survey is long.  I don't think that's controversial.

I started it but abandoned it about 10 minutes in.

If we could save the started portion and continue at a later date I'd be much more likely to finish it.

Comment: To save the survey results you'd need to associate the (partially complete) survey data with your account, making it no longer anonymous.

Comment: @Servy ah, yes.  I hadn't thought of that.  I guess if it has to be anonymous then you are right.  Perhaps this could be an optional feature.

Comment: @honk, yes looks like it. Shoot, I did a search and everything before posting :(